# Hibernate interceptors for queries

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In our application we have entity updates through entity manager, hibernate session, jpql @Modifying repository queries, jpa repository delete/update and native queries

I tried to implement EmptyInterceptor and FlushEntityEventListener. This interceptor callbacks are not called in few cases. My use case is to intercept sql/entities to add some data fields, filters. In case of delete I am doing a separate transaction by calling a procedure to populate the audit related fields.

How can i achieve writing interceptor in one place so that I can intercept all forms of database updates/deletes using hibernate , spring data jpa. Any examples/tips can help.